# I wish to only gather 8 total characters from the zone capture using this code to filter

Tags: regex, regression

I am attempting to withdraw BM/03600 (replacing / with 1) from:

"1LIUYILLIIY Date: BM/03600 Invoice/Cr Note No: DU100462 Account No: Order/GRN No: B. MANGION Sales Rep: Terms:"

using this code:

"[ACCOUNTNO (replace "/","1")(match "[A-Z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]")]"

however i am receiving this output "BM103600DU100462", i require the first in the string to be selected with 8 total characters two Letters and 6 numeric being BM103600 only.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Remove all `+`s or use `[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}`

Comment: regex can function differently in different languages, it might be useful to say what language you are using, so if there turns out to be any problems with the expression for that particular language someone can help. This is probably not that important in this case however as I suppose Wiktor's suggestion will fix it.

Comment: Dear Wiktor , I am currently testing your answer. thanks

Comment: "[ACCOUNTNO (replace "/","1")(match "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}")]" is still giving me a second 8 character output ... i need the output to be unique meaning if in the given information there are two 8 Character outputs i need only the first.

Comment: @user254694 apologies but i am using regular expressions on scanner vision to withdraw specific information from a zone using metadata

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i still am in need of assistance as it has not worked. thanks

Comment: If you could explain where you are performing these actions, it would help. Probably, `match` does not search for a regex match in the middle of the string. Is there any relevant documentation?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using the expression editor of the software scannervision to modify and filter metadata captured from zoning on a document.